# Azure function returning old results

Tags: node.js, azure, datetime, azure-functions

I have an azure function that I am running daily, but for the past few days I noticed that my function is returning old results for example

Result when function ran at 8/16/2023 10:08AM CST (The file name should be the yesterday's date and current time in PST)

[image]

Result when function ran at 8/16/2023 12:17PM CST (notice file name is exactly the same, the current time didn't change at all)
[image]

Result when code ran at 8/17/2023 7:00AM CST
[image]

Result when code ran at 8/17/2023 10:15AM CST (exact same result as 7:00AM run)
[image]

This problem will fix itself when I make a push on github without changing anything, the code will run perfectly for one iteration, but for the next run it will again start returning results from an older run.

In the code I use node.js's library luxon to get the current date and time and the code uses it to run certain functions

```
const { DateTime } = require("luxon");
const { BlobServiceClient } = require("@azure/storage-blob");
const XLSX = require("xlsx");

const start_time = DateTime.now()
  .set({ hour: 0, minute: 0, second: 0, millisecond: 0 })
  .minus({ days: 1 });

const end_time = DateTime.now()
  .set({ hour: 23, minute: 59, second: 59, millisecond: 999 })
  .minus({ days: 1 });

const time_now = DateTime.now();

async function uploadFileToBlobStorage(filename, json) {
  const connectionString = process.env.blobStorageConnectionString;

  const blobServiceClient =
    BlobServiceClient.fromConnectionString(connectionString);

  const containerName = process.env.blobContainer;
  const containerClient = blobServiceClient.getContainerClient(containerName);

  const worksheet = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(json);
  const workbook = XLSX.utils.book_new();
  XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(workbook, worksheet, "Sheet1");

  // Write workbook to a binary buffer
  const excelBuffer = XLSX.write(workbook, {
    type: "buffer",
    bookType: "xlsx",
  });

  const blobName = `${time_now
    .minus({ days: 1 })
    .toFormat("yyyy-LL-dd-hh-mm-ss")}_${filename}.xlsx`;

  const blockBlobClient = containerClient.getBlockBlobClient(blobName);

  await blockBlobClient.uploadData(excelBuffer, {
    blobHTTPHeaders: {
      blobContentType:
        "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet",
    },
  });
```

Could anyone tell me why the function is not returning accurate results.

P.S. -> It works perfectly every time locally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed it. Turn's out I was initializing time outside `module.exports` , because of this Azure function wasn't reinitializing time every time it ran, moving the time initialization inside `module.exports` fixed my issue

```
module.exports = async function (context, req) {
  try {
    const start_time = DateTime.now()
      .set({ hour: 0, minute: 0, second: 0, millisecond: 0 })
      .minus({ days: 1 });
    const end_time = DateTime.now()
      .set({ hour: 23, minute: 59, second: 59, millisecond: 999 })
      .minus({ days: 1 });
    const time_now = DateTime.now();
    .
    .
    .
    .
```

Answer (score 0):

***I made some changes to your code and the blob uploaded successfully to my storage account container.***

**Code:**

```js
const { DateTime } = require("luxon");
const { BlobServiceClient } = require("@azure/storage-blob");
const XLSX = require("xlsx");

module.exports = async function (context, myTimer) {
  try {
    console.log("blobStorageConnectionString:", process.env.blobStorageConnectionString);
    console.log("blobContainer:", process.env.blobContainer);

    const filename = "example";

    const jsonData = [
      { name: "Alice", age: 25 },
      { name: "Bob", age: 30 }
    ];

    const start_time = DateTime.now()
      .set({ hour: 0, minute: 0, second: 0, millisecond: 0 })
      .minus({ days: 1 });

    const end_time = DateTime.now()
      .set({ hour: 23, minute: 59, second: 59, millisecond: 999 })
      .minus({ days: 1 });

    const time_now = DateTime.now();

    await uploadFileToBlobStorage(filename, jsonData, time_now);

    context.log("Function executed successfully.");
  } catch (error) {
    context.log.error("An error occurred:", error.message);
  }
};

async function uploadFileToBlobStorage(filename, json, time_now) {
  try {
    const connectionString = process.env.blobStorageConnectionString;

    const blobServiceClient =
      BlobServiceClient.fromConnectionString(connectionString);

    const containerName = process.env.blobContainer;
    const containerClient = blobServiceClient.getContainerClient(containerName);

    const worksheet = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(json);
    const workbook = XLSX.utils.book_new();
    XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(workbook, worksheet, "Sheet1");

    const excelBuffer = XLSX.write(workbook, {
      type: "buffer",
      bookType: "xlsx",
    });

    const blobName = `${time_now
      .minus({ days: 1 })
      .toFormat("yyyy-LL-dd-hh-mm-ss")}_${filename}.xlsx`;

    const blockBlobClient = containerClient.getBlockBlobClient(blobName);

    await blockBlobClient.uploadData(excelBuffer, {
      blobHTTPHeaders: {
        blobContentType:
          "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet",
      },
    });

    console.log("File uploaded successfully:", blobName);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("An error occurred:", error.message);
  }
}
```

**.env** :

```js
blobStorageConnectionString="<Connec_string>"
blobContainer="<container_name>"
```

**Output:**

The Timer Trigger function runs successfully and blob uploaded successfully like below,

[image]

The blob uploaded to storage account at Azure Portal as below,

[image]

Then, I deployed the above code to my function app and it deployed successfully as below,

[image]

I run the function in function app at Azure Portal and it runs successfuly like below,

[image]

Comment: My code works perfectly fine for me, my issue is with Azure function. The issue I am facing is let's suppose I run the function it will run and save the file with yesterday's date and current time, now if I run the function again after an hour it will still give me the same time (1hr prior time), i.e. it's not giving me current results, it's giving older results.

Comment: I was able to update current time stamp while running the given code. When I trigger the function again it updates the timestamp along with yesterday date in locally and azure also.

Comment: ok, I was able to do the same, but suddenly it stopped giving me current results. I have no idea what happened as I didn't change anything major.